# Как посчитать количество товаров и сумму в корзине localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Делаю корзину по [примеру](https://incode.pro/javascript/sozdaem-korzinu-pokupatelja-na-chistom-javascript-i-localstorage.html). Как посчитать количество товаров в корзине и общую сумму?
В localstorage сохраняются: id товара, название, цена, количество.
Получается нужно посчитать сумму количеств и сумму цен.
Блин, как это сделать?

```
// Получаем данные из LocalStorage
function getCartData(){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}
function getCarttotal(){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.length);
}
// Записываем данные в LocalStorage
function setCartData(o){
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(o));
    return false;
}
// Добавляем товар в корзину
function addToCart(e){
    this.disabled = true; // блокируем кнопку на время операции с корзиной
    var cartData = getCartData() || {}, // получаем данные корзины или создаём новый объект, если данных еще нет
            parentBox = this.parentNode, // родительский элемент кнопки &quot;Добавить в корзину&quot;
            itemId = this.getAttribute('data-id'), // ID товара
            /*itemImg = parentBox.getAttribute('src').innerHTML, */ // изображение товара
            itemTitle = parentBox.querySelector('.item_title').innerHTML, // название товара
            itemPrice = parentBox.querySelector('.item_price').innerHTML; // стоимость товара
    if(cartData.hasOwnProperty(itemId)){ // если такой товар уже в корзине, то добавляем +1 к его количеству
        cartData[itemId][2] += 1;
    } else { // если товара в корзине еще нет, то добавляем в объект
        cartData[itemId] = [itemTitle, itemPrice, 1];
    }
    // Обновляем данные в LocalStorage
    if(!setCartData(cartData)){ 
        this.disabled = false; // разблокируем кнопку после обновления LS
        cartPrev.innerHTML = 'Товар добавлен в корзину.';
        setTimeout(function(){
            cartPrev.innerHTML = ' ';
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: покажите пример того, что у вас хранится в localStorage

Comment: {"1":["Chargana","215",6],"3":["Khaan Tea","215",1],"7":["Chargana","215",1]}

Comment: 3 наименования, первого товара 6,второго и третьего по 1 шт.

Answer (score 1):

можете попробовать что-то вроде такого. Рискнул предположить что Вам понадобится обьект с результатом для дальнейшей работы

```
let obj = {"1":["Chargana","215",6],"3":["Khaan Tea","215",1],"7":["Chargana","215",1]}; // mock data

Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev,el,i,ar) => {
 prev.amount = prev.amount || 0;
 prev.sum = prev.sum || 0;
 prev.amount += a[el][2];
 prev.sum += parseInt(a[el][1]);   
 return prev;
},{} ) // {amount: 8, sum: 645}
```

либо же `Object.keys( getCartData() ).reduce ...`

Comment: немного не понял как использовать( здесь let obj = нужно получить данные из localstorage?(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))

Comment: @Виктор у вас есть функция `getCartData` , по сути это и есть Ваш `obj`. Немного ошибся в нейминге - обновил ответ